# Override a module in plone's eggs?

Tags: python, portlet, plone, egg

I want to override a method (`assignment_mapping_from_key`) in:

```
eggs/plone.app.portlets-1.1.5.1-py2.4.egg/plone/app/portlets/utils.py
```

...because when I set a portlet in `portlets.xml`, I have to use a full path in `key` attribute and I don't have it (production and development servers have different urls), I want to use a relative one. I would like to "override" this module inside my own personal module.

Is this possible? I can't upgrade this egg and don't have access to the egg on server.

Comment: The egg already supports relative keys: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.portlets#b2-2010-01-25. Don't know if your Plone version works with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say I would recommend it, but you can have a look at:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.monkeypatcher/1.0.1

which may help you do what you want to do, even if it is a bad idea.

In general, Plone is designed to be customized inside your own personal module, but not necessarily in the way you describe (think custom content types, themes, etc.)

Also, you may want to describe what you are trying to do in general (big picture) vs. asking how to override assignment_mapping_from_key.

Comment: I said what I'm trying to do, I want to create a portlet in portlets.xml, but using a relative path on key attribute, not an absolute one. The plone.app.portlets 1.1.5 only accepts absolute path, t throws an error otherwise. I think this is resolved in newer versions, but I can't upgrade.

Comment: I think this module is exactly what I was looking for in this scenario, I'm going to take a look at it... thanks!

Comment: this add-on is shipped with plone

Answer (score 1):

You can't override a method, but why would you not just write your own? You can use a custom import handler (what's sometimes called an "import_various handler") to call such a method in Python code.

I think the key ought to be relative to the Plone site root, mind, so maybe what you've discovered is a bug/misfeature in Plone.

Comment: This issue has been already address by maurits: http://dev.plone.org/plone/changeset/32867/plone.app.portlets/trunk/plone/app/portlets/utils.py